# Proper name for this distribution type

Tags: distributions

I need help in defining the type of distribution used in software so that I could use some standard distribution library for this purpose. I apologize for not using proper terms. It takes "center" value and an alpha parameter (0 to 1) and produces N values within a given range, so that values are "clustered" around this "center" value. The less alpha the less they are "centered".

For example, if I feed a range of 1-5 with center at 4, alpha=0.5 and ask for 20 values the result will look something like this:

```
1:1 times
2:3 times
3:4 times
4:7 times
5:5 times
```

You get the idea. Thanks!

P.S. In case it might help, I provided some extracts from code

The code for probability density function:

```
private function assessProbabilityDensityFunction(){
        $probabilityDensityFunction=array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->valueRange->getNumberOfValues(); $i++)
            $probabilityDensityFunction[$i] = $this->probabilityFunction() * $this->probabilityCenteredCoefficient($i);
        return $probabilityDensityFunction;
    }

private function probabilityFunction(){
        return (1 - $this->settings->getAlpha()) / (1 - pow($this->settings->getAlpha(), $this->valueRange->getNumberOfValues() - $this->CentralValueSerialNumber() + 1) + $this->settings->getAlpha() - pow($this->settings->getAlpha(), $this->CentralValueSerialNumber()));
    }
private double centerBasedCoefficient(int valueIndex) {
            return Math.pow(parameters.alpha, distanceFromCenter(valueIndex)+1);
        }

private function distanceFromCentralValue($serialNumber){
        return abs($this->CentralValueSerialNumber() - $serialNumber - 1);
    }
```

And here's the cumulative function code

```
private function assessCumulativeDistributionFunction(){
    $cumulativeDistributionFunction = array();
    $cumulativeDistributionFunction[0] = $this->probabilityFunction->getValue(0);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->getValueRange()->getNumberOfValues(); $i++)
        $cumulativeDistributionFunction[$i] = $cumulativeDistributionFunction[$i - 1] + $this->probabilityFunction->getValue($i);
    return $cumulativeDistributionFunction;
}
```

And here's how we get distributed values

```
public function getValue(){
   return  $this->multinomialDistribution()+$this->cumulativeFunction->getValueRange()->getFromValue();
}

private function multinomialDistribution(){
   $rnd= lcg_value(); // random (0,1)
   for ($i=0; $i<$this->cumulativeFunction->getValueRange()->getNumberOfValues(); $i++)
     if ($this->cumulativeFunction->getValue($i) > $rnd) return $i;
   throw new Exception("Should always return a value");
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if, in place of the code, you'd provide the math.

Comment: I am close to figuring out the math from the code, but the definition of the `probabilityCenteredCoefficient` function is missing.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated code with this function. Its a short one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a bit confusing (comments would be nice). My guess is that you're trying to generate something like a discrete [Beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). I'm not sure what that would be though...

Comment: A discrete gamma won't be confined to a finite range, but a discrete beta will do the trick.  (A discrete gamma generalizes the geometric distribution, which itself is just a discrete exponential.)

Comment: Right! I've edited my answer.